# Resizable Scrolling layout with softKeyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm creating an Android application which requires a (1) static 40px tall Container (linear layout at the moment), (2) a scrollable-dynamically loaded content layout (ScrollView wrapped LinearLayout at the moment), (3) and an entry/answer field.

The Idea is (2) the scrollable-dynamically loaded content should be resized so that no matter what the (1) answer field and (3) container are visible. Also, I need every bit of content-within the dynamically loaded portion-able to be viewed.

**The problem** is that when the soft keyboard is shown I am getting a pan upward which hides the 40px container as well as a portion of my scrollable region (I can scroll all the way up and indeed the top few lines of my scrollable portion cannot be reached).

The activities entry in manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx.paid.activities.GamePlayActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|adjustResize"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/game_play_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/activity_home_screen">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:background="#FF000000"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/game_play_table"/>
    </ScrollView>
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/game_play_answer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:layout_margin="3sp"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated-I've been searching and trying different implementations found on stackoverflow however I have not met my requirement yet.